# Automatic line breaking for two-column text

Tags: line-breaking, two-column, sv-classes

I am using the following document class:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
```

Unfortunately, the two columns of output text just look horrible as they
are not properly aligned on the right-hand side of the text. I am just wondering
whether I can automatically tell LaTeX to align it nicely on the right-hand side
or if I have to manually tell LaTeX when to break a line as this is sometimes not
happening.

Comment: Could you create a full example where we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823714/automatic-line-break-in-latex-for-2-column-text?noredirect=1). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: In the minimal example `\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}\usepackage{lipsum}\begin{document}\lipsum[1-9]\end{document}` the alignment in the columns are justified. I'm using [this version of `svjour3`](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3/global.zip). Are your alignment issues dealing with poor hyphenation?

Answer (score 23):

It is indeed possible to reproduce the described behavior with [the `svjour3` document class for SPringer journals](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3/global.zip) with the following minimal code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

The highlighting was added manually:

[image]

The reason this is occurring is that TeX was not able to meet all the rules for spacing as per the `Overfull \hbox` messages.  One way to fix this is to add `\sloppy` which relaxes the rules for inter word spacing.  See the answers to [Why is text being placed beyond the specified line width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18210/why-is-text-being-placed-beyond-the-specified-line-width) for a more detailed explanation.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}\sloppy
\lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

Alternatively, as Marco suggested, you could add `\usepackage{microtype}` to the preamble.  See the [microtype package documentation](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype)  for more details.

If you are not set on justified text, you can use `\raggeddright`, or `\RaggedRight` from [the ragged2e package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e).

Comment: You can also use the package `microtype`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I think that is a better solution. Perhaps you should add that as an answer.

Comment: You can edit your answer. It isn't a competition here ;-)

Comment: Even \sloppy works with ACM sig-alternate class file too. That was great. But it waste some space for automatic alignment.

Comment: @Espanta: Not sure how I can help with such little information. I'd suggest you post a new question and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem. You can reference this question if it is relevant.

Comment: My problem is already solved using sloppy tag and I have no more problem. Thanks.