# Four Language Parallel Column Book

Tags: tables, spacing, formatting, books

I am trying to format a four column parallel text in four different languages to display on two pages with two columns per page.

I have tried using `ledpar` and parallels but I cannot get it to work.  I tried using opposing pages and then using a two-column `tabular` on each page to display the four languages, but `tabular` isn't supported by either `ledpar` or `parallels`.

Using the `tabular` environment inside of `ledmac` won't work because it does not support line breaks inside a cell.

Is there a way to display my text so each corresponding paragraph appears at the same horizontal location across the columns and pages?
Any help or ideas as to which direction to go would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I removed the "thanks". This is just the custom here. Thanks is best expressed through upvoting answers that help you.

Comment: Related Question: [how do i create parallel text aligned by paragraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/878/how-do-i-create-parallel-text-aligned-by-paragraph)

Comment: Have you considered using landscape pages?

Comment: By landscape pages do you mean making a page twice as wide? My page size is 6"x9" so I could make a page 12"x9", but how would I adjust the page numbers to work?

Comment: @Caleb: Were you able to solve this problem? I'm also trying to get four columns in parallel spread over two pages.

Answer (score 4):

Using [the `parcolumns` pacakge](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns) mentioned in the solution at [How do I create parallel text aligned by paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/878/how-do-i-create-parallel-text-aligned-by-paragraph) seems to work nicely.

Each section is to be placed within:

```
\begin{paracol}{4}
\end{paracol}
```

where the `4` is the number of columns.  Then `\switchcolumn[<n>]`, where `<n>` specifies the column (either `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3` for the 4 columns) is used to specify that the text following is for that specific columns within the `paracol` environment.

[image]

### Known Issues:

- Since the colunms aren't very wide there are issue with text overflowing. So the `microtype` package and `\sloppy` were used. See [automatic line breaking for two column text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32202/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{4}\sloppy
    \switchcolumn[0]\noindent
    \textbf{Column 1 text:}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed accumsan nulla ac ipsum elementum interdum. 
    Praesent ultricies faucibus turpis, non scelerisque nisi bibendum et. 

\switchcolumn[1]\noindent
    \textbf{Column 2 text:}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed accumsan nulla ac ipsum elementum interdum. 
    Praesent ultricies faucibus turpis, non scelerisque nisi bibendum et. 
    Phasellus quis ultricies sapien. 

\switchcolumn[2]\noindent
    \textbf{Column 3 text:}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\switchcolumn[3]\noindent
    \textbf{Column 4 text:}
    Integer iaculis nibh at orci hendrerit et elementum enim luctus. 
\end{paracol}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip
\begin{paracol}{4}\sloppy
    \switchcolumn[0]\noindent
    \textbf{Column 1 text:}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed accumsan nulla ac ipsum elementum interdum. 
    Praesent ultricies faucibus turpis, non scelerisque nisi bibendum et. 

\switchcolumn[1]\noindent
    \textbf{Column 2 text:}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed accumsan nulla ac ipsum elementum interdum. 
    Praesent ultricies faucibus turpis, non scelerisque nisi bibendum et. 
    Phasellus quis ultricies sapien. 
    Aliquam venenatis dolor libero, a dignissim nisi. 
    In ut magna a erat blandit facilisis. 
    Nulla vitae urna et nisl dignissim condimentum condimentum vitae mi. 
    Donec sed eros id nibh posuere posuere

\switchcolumn[3]\noindent
    \textbf{Column 4 text:}
    Integer iaculis nibh at orci hendrerit et elementum enim luctus. 
    Nulla varius mauris adipiscing libero vulputate condimentum. Suspendisse porta consequat neque, tincidunt fermentum risus aliquet ac. 
    Curabitur sed dui orci, eget rutrum quam. 
    Suspendisse potenti.
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the columns spread across two pages in portrait?  I need a way to have an accurate page count so I don't know if making my pages twice as wide will work.

Comment: @Caleb: Sorry, I don't know how to do that for the general case where the text in any column might not fit on one page. If it always fits on one page just using multiple two column arrangements should work.

Comment: @Caleb: You could also try using two separate documents with two column layout and use [the `pfdpages` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/) to put them together into one document.

Comment: Note that paracol and parcolumns are not the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I just found something that might help you: http://uucode.com/blog/2010/12/06/multi-page-tables-with-inter-row-page-breaks/

Ok, there are only three columns, but have a look at the pdf, this is close to what you ask. The columns are even spread across two pages.

Comment: That would work really well if there was a way to have it span two pages horizontally, but this looks like it is just spanning multiple pages vertically. Unless if I am missing something.