# When I prevent hyphenation using an \mbox, the box gets pushed into the right margin

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, hyphenation

I've used \mbox to prevent LaTeX from breaking certain long words into hyphenated pairs. Now I have a new problem: the unbroken words are extending into the right margin. Here's some minimal sample code that reproduces my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft,letterpaper]{report}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.8in}

\begin{document}
  We summarize our method in algorithm 1. The functions \mbox{``Update''}
  and \mbox{``BatchUpdate''} implement single and multi-constraint updates
  as described above, using interpolated solving to solve for no more than
  $D_{max}$ nodes at a time. The \mbox{``GetUpstreamGPSes($b$, $n$)''}
  function crawls up the tree from node $b$, and returns the first $n$ GPS
  edges along that path.
\end{document}
```

When I compile this with pdflatex, the `"BatchUpdate"` and `"GetUpstreamGPSes(b, n)"` function names get pushed into to right margin. I wanted them to get moved to the next line.

How can I prevent particular words from being broken across lines, while preventing them from extending into the right margin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try  `\sloppy` ([How can I make my text never go over the right margin by always hyphenating or breaking on word-boundaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/how-can-i-make-my-text-never-go-over-the-right-margin-by-always-hyphenating-or-b)).

I found that in the Related Links to your question. It worked for me with your text.

To fix just a part of the document:

> surround the offending paragraph with `\begin{sloppypar}` and
> `\end{sloppypar}` commands. Then LaTeX will not break words up but rather
> will allow more spacing between words in the given paragraph.

(from [http://ece.uprm.edu/~caceros/latex/introduction.pdf](http://ece.uprm.edu/%7Ecaceros/latex/introduction.pdf))

Comment: Is there no way of fixing this problem without affecting the whole document? The example I quoted is just part of a 100-page document. It'd be nice if I could just tell LaTeX not to push those three particular mboxes into the right margin, rather than making a systematic change to how it performs line breaks everywhere.

Comment: @SuperElectric Answer edited to answer this question.