# Automatic linebreak on specific character

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

Based on my old question [Push long words in a new line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62333/push-long-words-in-a-new-line), I search for a possibility to allow linebreak on specific character.

For example in my case I want to break on "_" (underscore).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Finally there is a simple solution using \textsc{\textbf{XMLResource.OPTION\_RECORD\_UNKNOWN\_FEATURE}} option. And the
text must go on \ldots.
\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can issue an `\allowbreak` wherever needed, as is proposed in [Allow line break, but without inserting a dash](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26174/5764).

Comment: Yeah that is true, but I want a "dynamic" solution for a begin/end block, because I want to create a template.

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you use the `\discretionary` command for hyphens.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\let\underscore\_
\renewcommand{\_}{\discretionary{\underscore}{}{\underscore}}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Finally there is a simple solution using  
\textsc{\textbf{XMLResource.OPTION\_RECORD\_UNKNOWN\_FEATURE}} option. And the
text must go on \ldots.
\par
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Use `\discretionary{}{\underscore}{\underscore}` instead if you wish the underscore to be placed on the next line, or `\discretionary{\underscore}{\underscore}{\underscore}` to get the character both before and after the line break.

`\discretionary` is the hook in to TeX's hyphenation scheme.  In some languages, including German, words can change spelling when they are hyphenated, and this command was introduced by Knuth to help cover such situations.  `\discretionary{a}{b}{c}` prints `c` if there is no linebreak, otherwise it prints `a` before the linebreak and `b` after.

If you want to limit this to one particular type of phrase then I suggest you use

```
\newcommand{\resource}[1]{\textbf{\let\underscore\_
  \renewcommand{\_}{\discretionary{\underscore}{}{\underscore}} #1}}
```

and write `\resource{XMLResource.OPTION\_RECORD\_UNKNOWN\_FEATURE}` in your text.  (I have removed the `\textsc` from your example as it had no effect.)

If you wish to use it in one section of the document, then you can similarly define an environment which inserts these definitions at the start, e.g.

```
\newenvironment{underscoresplit}{\let\underscore\_
  \renewcommand{\_}{\discretionary{\underscore}{}{\underscore}}}{}
```

used as

```
\begin{underscoresplit}
  Finally there is a simple solution using 
  \textsc{\textbf{XMLResource.OPTION\_RECORD\_UNKNOWN\_FEATURE}} option. And the
  text must go on \ldots.  
\end{underscoresplit}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any possibility to use it only in a begin/end block?

Comment: I have extended my answer to address this.

Answer (score 6):

You could define your own underscore macro, or redefine the original one, inserting an `\allowbreak` before or after:

```
\newcommand{\origunderscore}{}
\let\origunderscore\_
\renewcommand{\_}{\allowbreak\origunderscore}
```

You could omit the first line if you want, it's just to be safe.

- At first, we define a macro to reserve the name and so to get an error, if any package already defined it - to avoid accidentally redefining it
- We store the original underscore macro
- We redefine the underscore using the original macro, but inserting a possible breakpoint before

While this solves the case of your example, allowing breaks on an arbitrary character is more difficult. Options:

- You could make this character *active* and make a macro for it
- You could use XeTeX and `\XeTeXinterchartoks`
- You could use LuaTeX and `pre_linebreak_filter`

On [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org) we had a very similiar question, just the other way round: [Don't split words on certain letters](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=21029).

Comment: Thanks, is there any possibility to use it only in a begin/end block?

Comment: @CSchulz Sure! The first lines could still go to the preamble. The `\renewcommand` has effect just within the environment, if you place it there.

Answer (score 3):

you should use the package `url` with the command of the same name for such cases. Then it is broken by default at the _:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{url,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum[5]

\begin{sloppypar}
Finally there is a simple solution using \url{XMLResource.OPTION_RECORD_UNKNOWN_FEATURE} option. And the
text must go on \ldots.
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would not the best way to show constants as URL, but thanks.

Comment: you can define your own "URL" command  which uses only the same line breaking but another font, eg small caps: `\DeclareUrlCommand\myCommand{\urlstyle{sc}}`

Comment: @Herbert: `\urlstyle{sc}` doesn't work, you need to use `\DeclareUrlCommand\XML{\urlstyle{rm}\scshape}`