# Macro without delimiter

Tags: macros, tex-core

I want to define a macro that behaves like `\ttfamily`, i.e. it should read everything until `}` (or `\endgroup`?) as a parameter.

I.e. this

```
{\mynewmacro lorem ipsum
 dolores
}
```

should be equivalent to this

```
\mymacro{lorem ipsum
 dolores
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: your two requests are somewhat incompatible, `\ttfamily`  does not read ahead to the end of the group, it is not equivalent to a macro with argument in the way you suggest with `\mymacro`

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to show your use-case of `\mymacro`.

Comment: This looks like an “X-Y problem” (that is, you actually want to do Y, and you find out that you *could* do it, if only you were able to do X—which, unfortunately, you are not; so you ask how to do X, but what you actually want to achieve is Y).  If so, please tell us what Y is: perhaps, we could suggest a different way to achieve it that doesn’t require going through X.

Comment: @GuM: The issue I actually have is that when using `\texttt` you sometimes get overfull boxes, because hyphenation doesn't work properly. That's a known issue. I want to insert a `\linebreak[1]` after every character so as mentioned here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324042. I want a new command that replaces `\texttt` and ideally I also want a command that replaces `\ttfamily` to have that functionality. But it appears that `\ttfamily` is special in that sense.

Comment: @Volker There are so many places where such a `\mynewmacro` could go wrong that's better to give up with it. Since you want to process text in a special way, a command with argument is what you need.

Comment: @Volker This would be like asking `\newmbox` so you can say `{\newmbox abc}` instead of `\mbox{abc}`. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @egreg: I understand, thanks for your input. I'll try to avoid it.

Comment: @Volker it isn't that "hyphenation doesn't work properly" it is that hyphenation is deliberately disabled, it is trivial to define a tt font without hyphenation being disabled. A fragile parsing ahead for a close of group is completely the wrong way to attack this. Especially in latex where end of group is more likely to be `\end{foo}` than `}` a syntax such as you suggest is never going to work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I find this highly non trivial. Suppose I want to define a new column type so I can typeset an entire table in texttt. Here I'd use `\ttfamily`. How would I also have the feature that long words don't run into the next cell or the document margin? I don't care about proper hyphenation because the words may not be  english words, but hashes or other random strings of characters.

Comment: for that you don't really want hyphenation no point in trying to match words in natural language to get correct hyphenation, there are answers here about allowing long strings to break, I'll see if I can find....

Comment: also of course neither egreg's nor manuel's solution would work for table cells were the group ends with `&` or `\\ ` rather than `}`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324042/linebreaks-in-long-character-strings/324048#324048

Comment: to apply the macro with argument to a table cell use (say) `makecell` package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The macro `\ttfamily` does not read up to `}`: it is a declaration that sets (locally) the current font and its action continues until the current group ends.

You can do this, but it's conceptually wrong to begin with.

```
\long\def\mymacro#1{--#1--}
\long\def\mynewmacro{\egroup\iftrue\expandafter\mymacro\expandafter{\else}\fi}

\mymacro{lorem ipsum
 dolores
}

{\mynewmacro lorem ipsum
 dolores
}

\bye
```

The `\egroup` balances the initial `{`; then we have the problem to make `\mymacro` into seeing an explicit `{` and to get rid of the necessary `}` (because `\def` wouldn't accept an unbalanced list of tokens). The `\iftrue` test follows the true branch; actually what it does is simply disappearing, leaving

```
\expandafter\mymacro\expandafter{\else}\fi
```

on the input stream, but with TeX knowing it should ignore the `\else` part. With `\expandafter` we reach this `\else`, whose expansion removes everything up to `\fi`. So at the end we remain with

```
\mymacro{\fi
```

so by general rule `\mymacro` will read up to the matching `}`. The remaining `\fi` will expand leaving nothing at all.

Note, however, that you *can't* call this as `\begingroup\mynewmacro ...\endgroup` nor use `\bgroup` and `\egroup`.

Comment: `\begingroup \mynewmacro hello egreg\endgroup`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The OP wanted braces. `;-)`

Comment: Why also fail with `\bgroup \mynewmacro  hello egreg \egroup`?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the code a bit? The `\iftrue` trick looks interesting.

Comment: @Fran basically your `bgroup` example fails as you asked that it acts like a macro with arguments and you can not (for any macro taking an argument) use `\mymacro \bgroup ...\egroup` the argument of the macro is just `\bgroup` not the whole group.

Comment: A classic alternative, if I remember correctly, `\def\mynewmacro{\aftergroup\mymacro\aftergroup{}}`.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, it's a possible alternative.

Comment: @Manuel: Why don’t you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Manual: Great! I like yours better because it's so short. And it appears to be just what I need. If this is bad practice somehow I'm open to learn why.

Comment: @GuM It's the same idea than this answer: close the opened group, and then leave `\mymacro{` in there. egreg solution does that by putting `}\mymacro{}` and removing with a trick the last `}` before expanding `\mymacro`, and what this does is write `\mymacro{}` and moving with a trick the two tokens `\mymacro` and `{` to after the group closes, thus effectively leaving `}\mymacro{`.

Comment: @Volker You can use it, but I don't see a reason to write a different answer, I'll leave it in the comments.

Comment: @Manuel: Yes, both solutions were already clear to me :-)  I was just suggesting that yours deserves some upvotes too!  I actually prefer the `\aftergroup` trick, it’s both more elegant and more efficient, and this, IMHO, is the reason for writing a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the following example

- the macro `\FetchTillCloseBrace{\macro}` fetches everything till the next unmatched closing brace and passes that as undelimited argument to \macro, re-inserting that unmatched closing brace.
- the macro `\CopyBehindCloseBrace` is an example of how to put/copy tokens from inside a pair of braces forming a local scope behind the closing brace of that scope.

Be aware that processing via macros/macro arguments breaks things that rely on reading and tokenizing things under different catcode-régime, e.g., `\verb` and the like.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@PullOutFirstUndelimitedArgument{<action>}%
%%                                    {{<e_k>}{<e_(k+1)>}..{<e_n>}}%
%% yields
%%  <action>{<e_k>}{{<e_(k+1)>}..{<e_n>}}
%% It must be ensured that list is not empty!
%%......................................................................
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@KeepFirstTillSelDOM{}%
\long\def\UD@KeepFirstTillSelDOM#1#2\UD@SelDOM{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@PullOutFirstUndelimitedArgument[2]{%
    \expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter{%
    \expandafter{%
    \@firstoftwo{}#2}}{\UD@ExtractFirstListElementLoop{#2\UD@SelDOM}{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstListElementLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{#1}}%
  {%
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstListElementLoop
    \expandafter{%
    \UD@KeepFirstTillSelDOM#1}%
  }%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \CopyBehindCloseBrace
%%
%%   {<token sequence A>\CopyBehindCloseBrace{<tokens to appear only behind closing brace}<tokens to be copied behind closing brace>}
%% yields:
%%   {<token sequence A><tokens to be copied behind closing brace>}<tokens to appear only behind closing brace>{<tokens to be copied behind closing brace>}
%%......................................................................
\newcommand\FetchTillCloseBraceStart[2]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PullOutFirstUndelimitedArgument
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo\string}{}%
  {#2}%
}%
\newcommand\CopyBehindCloseBrace{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \FetchTillCloseBraceStart{\@CopyBehindCloseBrace}%
}%
\newcommand\@CopyBehindCloseBrace[2]{%
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{{ }#2}#1{#2}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \FetchTillCloseBrace{\macro}
%%
%%   {<token sequence A>\FetchTillCloseBrace{\macro}<remaining tokens in brace group>}
%% yields:
%%   {<token sequence A>\macro{<remaining tokens in brace group>}}
%%......................................................................
\newcommand\FetchTillCloseBrace{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \FetchTillCloseBraceStart{\@PassToMacroInsideScope}%
}%
\newcommand\@PassToMacroInsideScope[2]{%
   \expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{{ }#1{#2}}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%%
%% {ABC \LowercaseTillCloseBrace DEF}
%%   -> {ABC \lowercase{DEF}}
%%
%%......................................................................
\newcommand\LowercaseTillCloseBrace{%
   \FetchTillCloseBrace{\lowercase}%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing

{This is rmfamily. \FetchTillCloseBrace{\textsf}This is sffamily.}
This is rmfamily.

\bigskip

{ABC \LowercaseTillCloseBrace DEF}
GHI

\bigskip

{%<--This starts the boldface-group
 \bfseries This is boldface.
 \CopyBehindCloseBrace{This is to appear only outside the boldface-group. \textit}%
 This is to be copied outside the boldface-group.
}%<--This ends the boldface-group

\bigskip

\def\tempa{This is tempa outside the local scope. }%
{%
  \def\tempa{This is tempa inside the local scope. }%

  \CopyBehindCloseBrace{}\tempa
}

% This does _not(!) work:
% {Text\CopyBehindCloseBrace{Bla}\verb$verbatim text?$}
%
% Nor does this work:
%
% {Text \FetchTillCloseBrace{\textbf}\verb&verbatim \TeX t&}
%
% While this works:
% {Text \bfseries\selectfont \verb&verbatim \TeX t&}

\end{document}
```

[image]