# A group macro from a command

Tags: macros, grouping

Goal: create a command that works within a group (a scope)

I am using `polyglossia` package to write bilingual texts. I want to create `\eng` declaration or switch to behave just like `\textenglish`:

```latex
{\eng this is an english text} this is a foreign text
```

This should be equivalent to:

```latex
\textenglish{this is an english text} this is a foreign text
```

Comment: All macros which do not perform global changes act only within their group. What is `\mycmd` supposed to do?

Comment: `\mycmd` is just any command that effect what is inside the group.

Comment: Recall, `\color`, `\bfseries`, or `tiny` don't take arguments (they are declarations or "switches", if you will).  If your `\mycmd` also doesn't take an argument, they you are good to go without anything special.  If `\mycmd` takes an argument, then it is not "just like" those other macros.

Comment: Basically, the answer depends on what `\mycmd` wants to do. If you give an example...

Comment: obeying grouping is the _default behaviour_ so your question as asked doesn't really have any answer. Note that `\color`, `\bfseries` etc have no access to the text that is in the current group, they just change the state and that state ends when the group ends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a declaration from a command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531174/how-to-make-a-declaration-from-a-command)

Comment: `\newcommand\mycmd{\bfseries\itshape\color{red}}` and then do `{\mycmd abc is some text}`, does what you want. If whatever you want to achieve is achievable just by changing some states (like the colour stack, the font in use, some sizes, etc.) you can do this just by changing the definition. If your macro needs access to the contents of the group, then just as others have already said, that's impossible.

Comment: Hello everyone. Thanks for your help. I have updated my question to give a concrete example of what exactly I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`polyglossia` provides the macro `\text⟨language name⟩{⟨text⟩}` which takes the text as argument, and the *switch* `\selectlanguage{⟨language name⟩}`. That's the one you want to use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newcommand*{\eng}{\selectlanguage{english}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Das ist auf Deutsch: \figurename.
{\eng This is english: \figurename.}
Das ist wieder auf Deutsch: \figurename.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This solves my problem. But I have posted my question initially as a general question about creating a switch from a command. I mean, how can I do this for other commands from different packages? Is there a recipe for it?

Comment: @AvidSeeker We have tried to explain to you in comments that there is no general answer to this. It depends on how the macro you are interested in has been defined to begin with. As long as you have only switches, they will always act locally. But does the macro take argument(s)? Well, then it depends on how they are processed.