# How to define a declaration based on a command?

Tags: macros

For typesetting in italics LaTeX provides the command `\textit{<some text>}` and also the declaration `\itshape` used as `{\itshape <some text>}`.

There is also the command `\MakeUppercase{<some text>}`. I would like to be able to have a declarative form like `{UppercaseIt <some text>}` but I have been unable to produce one. I tried to find the definitions of `textit` and `\itshape` in the hopes of doing something similar in transforming one into the other. I tried `texdoc article` but that didn't have the definitions so they must be somewhere else.

Comment: there is no way to do this in general

Comment: if you can guarantee the end of the group is a literal `}` not a table cell or end of environment etc then it's posssible to fake something.

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531174/1090 which was asked by ... you..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had forgotten that I had asked the question before but it was several months before there were any answers and I was not notified of them. Should I delete my question?

Comment: Peter, no harm done, this one is closed as duplicate so it doesn't really matter you could delete or leave it