# Linebreaks within a hyperlink?

Tags: hyperlink

I have a named link within my document. I want to allow line breaks of the text at an arbitrary position, preferred at some common know position but if it won't work out than at any kind of position.

While for the `\url` command there are some packages out (e.g. `xurl`) I haven't found a solution when using `\hyperlink`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,british]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[tracking=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10,final]{microtype} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback("fntFallback",{
    "DejaVu Sans:mode=harf",
    "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf"})}
\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xurl} 
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[pdfa, unicode, breaklinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
The labour participation rate in my own country is estimated to be 99.9\% in 2019 (%
\hyperlink{abc}{ILO/CSO/KRSO 2020})\newline
The labour participation rate in my own country is estimated to be 99.9\% in 2019 (%
\url{ILO/CSO/KRSO 2020})\newline

\hypertarget{abc}{sample anchor text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm using `lualatex 1.17.0` with `hyperref 2023-02-07 v7.00v`.

Comment: that is simply text, so everything that allows a line break works, e.g. `{ILO/CSO/KR\hspace{0pt}SO 2020}`.

Comment: Well then I need to take care on my own. Isn't there an automatic solution similar to xurl?

Comment: there are various packages around to split a string at some arbitrary place see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324042/2388 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595035/2388. It depends a lot on what you actually want and which chars will be in your string (e.g. non-ascii will not work well with url-like commands.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you for the various links you've sent. I finally found the https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422570/48642 which fits best since I have as well arbitrary text included. I was not aware that this might have an influence. Thx very much again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same line breaking as `\url` for example

`\hyperlink{abc}{\path{ILO/CSO/KRSO 2020}})`

`\path` is like `\url` but doesn't make a link. By default it uses `\texttt` but as with `\url` you can specify the font to use, by default it's defined via

`\DeclareUrlCommand\path{\urlstyle{tt}}`

Comment: Ahhh... Thx... I'll try tomorrow - this sounds promising ☺️

Comment: After trying many different approaches I have to admit I'm getting lost between different solutions. Using the path command solves somehow the problem but opens others. First of all the whitespace - but this could be handled with the option of `obeyspaces`. The other (main) problem is how to use special chars like `#@%`? By escaping them I can compile the TeX code but the the text has `\\` included. Is there a way to resolve it?