# Automatic line break on any character?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, wrap

I'm generating some latex from some information in a database.  I am putting all this information in a table, but some of the data in the cells are very long and have no obvious break points.  As a result, information is just continuing past the cell and thus not being seen.

Is there a way to tell LaTeX to break/wrap on any character? Or rather, is there a way to tell LaTeX to wrap on *all* characters?

Comment: As you are not providing any `MWE`, try with simple para mode definition `begin{tabular}{p{5pc}...)`

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324042/linebreaks-in-long-character-strings

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\section{Wrap word with \texttt{X} column of \texttt{tabularray} package in table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[l,m]Q[c,m]},vlines,hlines}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.&Test\\
\end{tblr}
\section{Wrap word with \texttt{seqsplit} package in text}
\seqsplit{Lorem\ ipsum\ dolor\ sit\ amet,\ consectetur\ adipisicing\ elit,\ sed\ do\ eiusmod\
tempor\ incididunt\ ut\ labore\ et\ dolore\ magna\ aliqua.\ Ut\ enim\ ad\ minim\ veniam,\
quis\ nostrud\ exercitation\ ullamco\ laboris\ nisi\ ut\ aliquip\ ex\ ea\ commodo\
consequat.\ Duis\ aute\ irure\ dolor\ in\ reprehenderit\ in\ voluptate\ velit\ esse\
cillum\ dolore\ eu\ fugiat\ nulla\ pariatur.\ Excepteur\ sint\ occaecat\ cupidatat\ non\
proident,\ sunt\ in\ culpa\ qui\ officia\ deserunt\ mollit\ anim\ id\ est\ laborum.}
\section{Wrap word with \texttt{tabularray} and \texttt{seqsplit} package in table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[l,m]Q[c,m]},vlines,hlines}
\seqsplit{Lorem\ ipsum\ dolor\ sit\ amet,\ consectetur\ adipisicing\ elit,\ sed\ do\ eiusmod\
tempor\ incididunt\ ut\ labore\ et\ dolore\ magna\ aliqua.\ Ut\ enim\ ad\ minim\ veniam,\
quis\ nostrud\ exercitation\ ullamco\ laboris\ nisi\ ut\ aliquip\ ex\ ea\ commodo\
consequat.\ Duis\ aute\ irure\ dolor\ in\ reprehenderit\ in\ voluptate\ velit\ esse\
cillum\ dolore\ eu\ fugiat\ nulla\ pariatur.\ Excepteur\ sint\ occaecat\ cupidatat\ non\
proident,\ sunt\ in\ culpa\ qui\ officia\ deserunt\ mollit\ anim\ id\ est\ laborum.}&Test\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]