# Custom line breaks in maketitle with authblk

Tags: line-breaking, titles, authblk

I am trying to modify the output of the affiliations defined with authblk to print each entry on consecutive lines, and when the text width is exceeded break the line at the symbol separating the different affiliations.

I tried adapting this solution from [Automatic linebreak on specific character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66583/automatic-linebreak-on-specific-character) unfortunately it does not work the way I want.

Here is an example of the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\renewcommand\Authfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\renewcommand\Authand{, }
\renewcommand\Authands{, }

% This did not work
\def\semicolon{;}
\let\semisep\semicolon
\renewcommand{\semicolon}{\discretionary{\semisep}{}{\semisep}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{\protect{\semicolon } \protect\Affilfont}
\makeatother

\title{Fix line breaks}

\author[1]{Author A}
\author[1]{Author B}
\author[2]{Author C}
\author[3]{Author D}
\author[4]{Author E}
\author[1]{Author F}

\affil[1]{Really really Really Name of Institute 1, City, State}
\affil[2]{Name of Institute 2, City, State}
\affil[3]{Name of Institute 3, City, State}
\affil[4]{Name of Institute 4, City, State}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

I want maketitle to have the authors and affiliations line break at separators like:\\
\begin{center}
\bfseries
Author A$^{1}$,
Author B$^{1}$,
Author C$^{2}$,
Author D$^{3}$,
Author E$^{4}$, \\ %have maketitle or authblk insert this linebreak
Author F$^{1}$    
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \itshape
    $^{1}$Really really Really Name of Institute 1, City, State; \\ %have maketitle or authblk insert this linebreak
    $^{2}$Name of Institute 2, City, State;
    $^{3}$Name of Institute 3, City, State; \\ %have maketitle or authblk insert this linebreak
    $^{4}$Name of Institute 4, City, State;
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image: working example output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm sure it would be possible (and meaningful) to force `authblk` to do it, but in the end I think it is much easier to just write `\author[1]{Author~A}` and so on...

Comment: Is there a way I can define a command to find replace a space with a tilde when processing. Perhaps some combination of xpatch and \StrSubstitute?

Comment: Again: possible? Yes. However (forgive the bluntness) I don't think it's worth it. Why write complicated TeX code when a sensible input does the same, only better?