# Automatic camel case breaking

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

Based on my old question [Push long words in a new line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62333/push-long-words-in-a-new-line), I search for a possibility to allow linebreak before a capital character in camel case terms.

For example the term **createUnspecifiedNodeErrorMarker** can be break into **create-Unspecified-Node-Error-Marker**.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
And another example the show must go on, but we have too less text (\textbf{createUnspecifiedNodeWarningMarker} and
\textbf{createUnspecifiedNodeErrorMarker}, sdjklashjksa \textbf{createUnspecifiedLinkWarningMarker} and
\textbf{createUnspecifiedLinkErrorMarker}).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Be (but only slightly) careful what you wish for. Compare: "StringRenderingEngine" with "String[space]RenderingEngine". If it splits in the wrong place you have ambiguity.

Comment: You are right, I only want to use it in an seperate environment, not for the whole document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeX would linebreak (hyphenate) the camel case words, but perhaps not where you wish eg

```
cre-a-te-Un-spec-i-fiedNodeEr-ror-Marker
```

shows the default hyphenation points (using the default US English hyphenation)

It wasn't clear if you wanted hyphens at the break points. I have assumed not. If you do then change `\penalty2` to `\-`.

[image]

This boxes the parts between capital letters so they don't break, and puts a small penalty before capitals so they can break.

As with anything using catcode changes (like `\verb` it will not work in the argument to another command)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\showhyphens{createUnspecifiedNodeErrorMarker}

\makeatletter
\def\zzz{\leavevmode\begingroup
\let\ifcase\iftrue
\def\or##1{%
  \catcode`##1\active\uccode`\~`##1\uppercase{%
    \def~{\egroup\penalty2\hbox\bgroup\string##1}}}%
\@Alph{}%
\@zzz}

\def\@zzz#1{\textbf{\hbox\bgroup#1\egroup}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test}


And another example the show must go on, but we have too less text (\zzz{createUnspecifiedNodeWarningMarker} and
\zzz{createUnspecifiedNodeErrorMarker}, sdjklashjksa \zzz{createUnspecifiedLinkWarningMarker} and
\zzz{createUnspecifiedLinkErrorMarker}).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to use it within captions?

Comment: it's a fragile command so `\protect\zzz` should do the right thing, oh apart from the catcode change part :(

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "oh apart from the catcode change part :("

Comment: But protect doesn't work with sections and so on, correct?

Comment: If one loads microtype there is a side effect: `! Package microtype Error: protrusion list `cmr-OT1' cannot load itself.`. One can avoid it by calling the bold font before it is used in the code (e.g. `\AtBeginDocument{{\bfseries}}`)

Answer (score 2):

An implementation in `expl3` that also allows a (named) color as optional argument to `\keyw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\keyw}{O{.}m}
 {
  \textcolor{#1}{ \bfseries \cschulz_keyw:n { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \cschulz_keyw:n
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    % if the current char is uppercase, add a discretionary hyphen
    \str_if_eq:eeT { ##1 } { \str_uppercase:n { ##1 } } 
     { \- }
    ##1
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

And another example the show must go on, but we have too less 
text (\keyw{createUnspecifiedNodeWarningMarker} sdjkle
\keyw{createUnspecifiedNodeErrorMarker}, sdjklashjksa 
\keyw{createUnspecifiedLinkWarningMarker} and
\keyw[red]{createUnspecifiedLinkErrorMarker}).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Expect several overfull boxes, anyway, as breaking only at capital letters is rather rigid.