# Automatic line breaking of camel case within \url

Tags: line-breaking, urls

I would like to break camel case text that is handed to the `\url{}` macro of `url.sty`. The solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66593/21591) does not work for text in captions, so it seems, ans in particular does not work for `\url{}`.

Is there a way to break the camel case as in:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\noindent{}Here some text, and
then \url{BreakThisCamelCaseForMeItWasChosenToMakeSomeTasksEasierButAlas.txt},
and then some more text to indicate the text width, showing that
the URL should break earlier.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\UrlSpecials{\camelurl}
\def\camelurl{%
\count@`a
\loop
\mathcode\count@"8000
\uccode`\~\count@\uppercase{\edef~{\mathchar\the\count@\noexpand\breakifupper}}%
\ifnum\count@<`\z
\advance\count@\@ne
\repeat}

\def\breakifupper#1{%
\ifcat .\noexpand#1%
\ifnum`#1>40
\ifnum`#1<91
\penalty\z@
\fi\fi\fi
#1%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\noindent{}Here some text, and
then \url{BreakThisCamelCaseForMeItWasChosenToMakeSomeTasksEasierButAlas.txt},
and then some more text to indicate the text width, showing that
the URL should break earlier.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't seam to work for me. Do I have to use `\camelurl{}` instead of url or should it work for `\url` automatically. (BTW: I'm using XeLaTeX could this be the reason, because the character range is hard coded in `\breakifupper`?)

Comment: @white_gecko the answer as posted works for me with pdflatex and xelatex it is true that it only allows a break point after a-z but really non ascii characters in URL ought to be `%ab` encoded anyway. The loop could of course be modified to cover other ranges than a-z similary the test for a following uppercase is assuming code point values in range 40-91.

Comment: Sorry. Its working for me. I was looking at a `\texttt{}` which didn't wrap the text for obvious reasons.

Comment: Is there something like that for `\texttt`
?

Comment: @white_gecko you can use exactly that but configure url to use tt font (which should be the default)

Comment: But `\url` and `\nolinkurl` are removing all spaces from the text, which is not what I want in `\texttt`.