# Hyphenating identifiers printed in typewriter font

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, typewriter

I'm typesetting identifier documentation by generating them from a database. These identifiers that are very free-format, i.e. using a
mixture of camel-Case and underscores etc. I want to print them in typewriter font, hyphenated.

I have managed the printing of the underscores identifiers with the help of TeX.SX, thanks very much.

However... hyphenation. I want to allow a linebreak between a lowercase
character and an uppercase character, and after `_` and `-`, and replace
the normal hyphen with another character (`\cdot` would be nice, but that's not a character in `T1`) to prevent ambiguity for the latter case.

I think I'd want keep the original hyphenation points (useful for
the string "modification" in my example). I guess breaking before or after a
number does not need special treatment.

Here is an example of my current `\identifier` command that does not add extra hyphenation points. I'm not understanding it well enough to mix in the code from e.g. [Automatic camel case breaking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66593/automatic-camel-case-breaking) though - could someone have a go at it for me please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % better underscore
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\makeatletter%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\identifier}[1]{%
  \begingroup\@activeus\scantokens{%
  \ifmmode%
    \expandafter\texttt%
  \else%
    \expandafter\textnhtt%
  \fi{#1}%
    \endinput}\endgroup}%
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_\relax
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def\@activeus{\catcode`\_=\active \let~\_}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}%
  \identifier{SmartModificationSense}
  \identifier{SmartModification_Sense}
  \identifier{Smart_Modification_Sense2}
  \identifier{smartModification_Sense2}
  \identifier{smartModi-fication_Sense2}
  \identifier{adj_Iref3_5percent}
  \identifier{enable_SPI_1}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds a centered dot if an identifier is split before an uppercase letter (not preceded by another uppercase letter) or after an underscore and allows normal hyphenation in word fragments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % better underscore
\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\identifier}{m}
 {
  \cmarqu_identifier:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_cmarqu_identifier_tl

\cs_new:Nn \cmarqu_identifier:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_cmarqu_identifier_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \B([^A-Z])([A-Z]) }
   { \1 \c{cmarqu_period:} \2 }
   \l_cmarqu_identifier_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \cD.}
   { \cO_\c{cmarqu_period:} }
   \l_cmarqu_identifier_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { \c{cmarqu_period:}\c{cmarqu_period:} }
   { \c{cmarqu_period:} }
   \l_cmarqu_identifier_tl
  \texttt{\tl_use:N \l_cmarqu_identifier_tl}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \cmarqu_period:
 {
  \nobreak
  \discretionary{\textperiodcentered}{}{}
  \nobreak\hspace{0pt}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}%
  \identifier{SmartModificationSense}
  \identifier{SmartModification_Sense}
  \identifier{Smart_Modification_Sense2}
  \identifier{smartModification_Sense2}
  \identifier{smartModification_Sense2}
  \identifier{adj_Iref3_5percent}
  \identifier{enable_SPI_1}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, after updating my Texlive installation, I had it working like a charm. One thing though - would it also be possible to change _all_ the hyphenation within such an identifier to the centered dot? I fear that the current behaviour is not easily deducible without much context (or explaining it in a "Typography" section).

Comment: @cmarqu Unfortunately not; the hyphenation character must belong to the same font. I guess it would be possible with LuaTeX.