# How to avoid global \sloppy with many \texttt

Tags: line-breaking, typography, typewriter

I read that using a global `\sloppy` is bad practice. I have a document with many variables of a source code that I reference as in `\texttt{VariableName}`. I use a lot of them both in normal paragraphs and sometimes in section titles. By default they are being handled terribly and produce a lot of overshoots on the right margin. So far I came up with the following solutions:

1. manually hyphenating `\texttt{Variable\-Name}` which is (a) terrible case-by-case work and (b) might suggest hyphenated variable names to the reader
2. manually breaking the line right before the variable `\\ \texttt{VariableName}` which is (a) again terrible case-by-case work and (b) produces empty space on the right margin (line not "full")
3. using `\sloppy` globally, apparently bad practice but in fact the only solution that I see which does not require me to go through my whole document and fix on case-by-case basis. This would be especially terrible if I, e.g. change margins in the end and have a bigger/smaller page and have to go through everything manually again. That is IMO not a solution.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: I would really use @egreg solution in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324869/hyphenating-identifiers-printed-in-typewriter-font  --- if you want a justified text and have long identifiers, you need to hyphenate them. The solution linked performs automatic hyphenation on uppercases and underscores, and use a "centered dot" which is in my opinion perfect for this case.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt ?

Comment: I would typeset these variables using `\url` of the `url` package (instead of `\texttt`), instructing the macro to break at any letter, with this preamble addition: `\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}\makeatother`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - very clever. Note though that if you also use `hyperref`, that package will try to turn your `\url` macros into hyperlinks.

Comment: One way to add some sloppiness on an as-needed basis is the \emergencystretch` setting, for example: `\setlength{\emergencystretch}{6pt}`. If I understand this correctly, LaTeX will then first try to typeset a paragraph using its usual strict settings, and if that fails, will make a second try that uses the specified amount of extra horizontal space.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Already `\sloppy` sets `\emergencystretch`; see my answer below. In fact, `\sloppy` sets it to the far larger (and therefore more useful) value of `3em`, which amounts to `30pt` at the default settings. IMO it makes no sense to declare “`\sloppy` is bad practice” and then implement a poorer version of `\sloppy` manually. :-) (In fact, simply increasing `\emergencystretch` without increasing `\tolerance` is likely to make TeX resort to the "emergency" even when there's no serious emergency.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - I nowhere denounced `\sloppy` as bad practice; I just offered an alternative for the OP to consider. Unlike  `\sloppy`, `\emergencystretch`  attempts to typeset each paragraph in a strict fashion first and resorts to doing it sloppily only when that initial strict attempt fails. The exact length value that I suggested was obviously not set in stone; it would be up to the OP to determine what value would be the best trade-off between unsloppy appearance and reduction of manual line breaking.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer `\sloppy` is defined using `\emergencystretch`. If you have an example where setting only `\emergencystretch` (without also increasing `\tolerance` as `\sloppy` does) results in *better* output, I'd like to see it. :-)

Comment: If you like the basic `\url` approach, but don't want hyperlinks, then perhaps an answer based on this one could achieve what you want:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219445/line-break-in-texttt/219497#219497

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how `\sloppy` is defined (from the LaTeX sources, which you can read with `texdoc source2e` or via [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf) or [texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf#page=393)):

[image: screenshot of definition of <code>\sloppy</code>]

So these are the things `\sloppy` does:

- Sets `\tolerance` to 9999: this is not as bad as the name makes it sound. If you're not inclined to pay attention to underfull/overfull box warnings and fix them, in fact this is never a bad idea: all that a higher `\tolerance` (but non-infinite, i.e. less than 10000) does is allow TeX to *consider* worse line breaks, while still trying to generate an optimal paragraph. It is highly unlikely to make the output worse and the worst you can say about it is that it makes TeX work harder, but on today's computers the difference can be measured in milliseconds.
- Sets `\hfuzz` and `\vfuzz` to `0.5pt`. This only affects what warning is *shown* to you: only lines which are overfull or underfull by more than `0.5pt` are warned about. (The default is `0.1pt`.)
- Sets `\emergencystretch` to `3em`. This is the most crucial thing for preventing overfull lines IMO (what you called “overshoots on the right margin”). It is additional stretch that TeX adds to each line, after everything else has failed. You can set it as large as you want, if you're willing to accept extra-large spaces between words on such lines. (If you're not going to rewrite text for dealing with overfull boxes, extra-large spaces are definitely better than lines sticking out of the right margin!)

Now that you know and understand what `\sloppy` does, you can decide for yourself whether or not you'd prefer to apply it globally, rather than go by maxims like “global `\sloppy` is bad practice”. There are cases where that makes sense, and cases where it doesn't: if you have such hard-to-break lines throughout your document, then it most definitely makes sense to globally take measures that will result in the best output.

---

Personally, for the case you mentioned (document with many hard-to-justify lines because of variable names in `\textt` forming unbreakable boxes), this would be my order of preference:

1. Leave everything at the default settings; manually watch out for and fix overfull and underfull boxes by rewriting text, etc. This degree of polishing you can do if your document is worth the effort and you're sure you've already polished the *content* enough (which you should always do first). Else, below I assume you're not going to manually fix overfull boxes.
2. Globally (across all paragraphs of this type) use whichever parameters of `\sloppy` you think you want: either `\sloppy` itself, or `\tolerance 9999` along with as much `\hfuzz` as you don't want to get warned about, and as much `\emergencystretch` as you can tolerate (the higher the better for avoiding overfull lines).
3. Give up on paragraph justification, and use ragged-right text. Text won't line up at the right margin, but you won't need any awkward spaces or hyphenation.
4. Use hyphenation inside the `\textt` variables, globally: there are ways to do this, but as you said it can suggest to the reader that the variable is hyphenated, which I would really avoid.

The choice between (2) and (3) (`\sloppy`-like, or ragged-right) would depend on the exact document. Of course everything is subjective and a function of your aesthetics.

Answer (score 6):

I would use `\sloppy` (or use `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package if you don't mind giving up the justified right margin.)

General advice about avoiding over stretched white space is general advice but it's mostly advice about natural language text and if what you are writing isn't natural language then different rules may apply (or there may be no rules and you have to do whatever you think best).

You don't need to do so much manual work. If you accept hyphenated variable names then you can re-enable hyphenation in the tt font, however I wouldn't do that, especially if `-` is a legal character in variable names in the language being documented.

Similarly you can define a command such that `\zz{MyVariable}` puts `MyVariable` in tt and makes a breakpoint before the word, leaving the line short if a break is taken at that point (as if `\\` had been used)  That's a possibility but if there a lot it's probably better to use `\RaggedRight`.

Or you can use `\sloppy` which is probably OK if you want justified paragraphs.

Answer (score 4):

For the specific paragraphs which have a lot of such function names use

```
\begin{sloppypar}
...
\end{sloppypar}
```

it makes more sense than a global `\sloppy`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution based on the `hyphenat` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}

\hyphenation{My-Terribly-Excru-ciating-ly-Long-Identi-fier-Thats-What-You-Get-For-Writing-Java}

\newcommand{\terrible}{{\ttfamily MyTerriblyExcruciatinglyLongIdentifierThatsWhatYouGetForWritingJava}}

\begin{document}
This document describes a new program for comparing two numbers according to size. One number is referred to as \texttt{a}, the other one as \terrible.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for information, TeX won't add hyphens after the 63rd character in a word. For instance it won't honor the discretionary hyphen between `Writing` and `Java`.