# camelCase text hyphenation with coloured text

Tags: color, hyphenation

Responding to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66593/automatic-camel-case-breaking/423240#423240), David Carlisle provided source code that automatically breaks or hyphenates camelCase words so that they may span multiple lines. Breaking or hyphenation occurs before capitals, e.g. camel-Case.

I have successfully used the code and altered it slightly to match my needs (used typewriter font as well as bold text):

```
\def\@zzz#1{\textbf{\texttt{\hbox\bgroup#1\egroup}}\endgroup}
```

However, I cannot colour the text. I have tried various things such as

- \textcolor inside David Carlisle's implementation, i.e.   `\def\@zzz#1{\textbf{\texttt{\hbox\bgroup\textcolor{mycustomcolor}{#1}\egroup}}\endgroup}`
  I also tried this with \textcolor outside \textbf
- creating a new command that uses \zzz (David Carlisle wrote this won't work, but I got desperate):
  `\newcommand{\coloredcamel}[1]{\textcolor{mycustomcolor}{\zzz{#1}}}`
- and a few other variants. For example, I tried the above with both the *color* package and the *xcolor* package. I also tried the `\color` command.

mycustomcolor was defined using `\definecolor{mycustomcolor}{RGB}{201, 20, 15}`

**Is it somehow possible to colour text in David Carlisle's implementation?** Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: I added color in an answer to the previous question.

Comment: Thank you @egreg! I upvoted you on the other question, but stuck with the solution posted here (never change a running system =) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\color` not `\textcolor` also the redefinition of `\ifcase` to `\iftrue` was a cheap trick to re-use `\Alph` to get a list of uppercase letters. It is only safe if no command uses `\ifcase` in the scope of the envrionment, which is apparently not the case for `xcolor` so this just defines a new list of uppercase rather than patchng `\@alph, but is otherwise identical code.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\showhyphens{createUnspecifiedNodeErrorMarker}
\def\zzcolor{\color{red}}
\makeatletter
\def\zzz{\leavevmode\begingroup
\def\zzelt##1{%
  \catcode`##1\active\uccode`\~`##1\uppercase{%
    \def~{\egroup\egroup\penalty2\hbox\bgroup\bgroup\zzcolor\string##1}}}%
\zz@Alph{}%
\@zzz}

\def\zz@Alph#1{%
   \zzelt A\zzelt B\zzelt C\zzelt D\zzelt E\zzelt F\zzelt G\zzelt H\zzelt I\zzelt J\zzelt
   K\zzelt L\zzelt M\zzelt N\zzelt O\zzelt P\zzelt Q\zzelt R\zzelt S\zzelt T\zzelt U\zzelt V\zzelt W\zzelt X\zzelt
    Y\zzelt Z}

\def\@zzz#1{\textbf{\hbox\bgroup\bgroup\zzcolor#1\egroup\egroup}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test}


And another example the show must go on, but we have too less text (\zzz{createUnspecifiedNodeWarningMarker} and
\zzz{createUnspecifiedNodeErrorMarker}, sdjklashjksa \zzz{createUnspecifiedLinkWarningMarker} and
\zzz{createUnspecifiedLinkErrorMarker}).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very, very much for your reply. **Is it possible to use the _xcolor_ package instead?** I tried replacing `\usepackage[color]` with `\usepackage[xcolor]` but that causes errors when compiling. I tried to debug or replace `\color` with `\textcolor` but my latex knowledge is nowhere near good enough for the kind of "low-level" code in your MWE. Sorry I wasn't clear about my need for _xcolor_ ... I only just realised myself that _tikz_ loads _xcolor_.

Comment: I tried using _xcolor_ with `\color` (i.e. only alteration to your MWE was `\usepackage[xcolor]`) but got several error messages, such as: "Undefined control sequence...", "Missing = inserted...", "Improper alphabetic constant...", "Missing number, treated as zero...", "Improper alphabetic constant..."

Comment: @Jay_At_Play oh yes so you do, sorry! can only require a minor change (xcolor is a compatible extension of color in almost all cases) but out of time now, I'll fix that later and ping you here

Comment: Thank you so much, you are amazing =) I'll try to pass on the favour and contribute to tex.StackExchange

Comment: @Jay_At_Play `xcolor`

Comment: Thank you very much! Your new implementation works. Only exceptions: as you described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66593/automatic-camel-case-breaking/423240#423240) it does not work in \caption{} or \todonote{}. As a workaround, I use my previous implementation `\newcommand{\zzzprevious}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}` whenever your solution is not viable. Thanks again!