# string of non-breaking spaces spilling into margin

Tags: spacing, margins

I have a string of expressions that should not be split across lines, so I have placed non-breaking spaces between them. However, they spill over into the margin. How do I fix this? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
This text shows that non-breaking spaces are not working properly: ``a:a~b:b~c:d~e:e~f:f~g:h''. \lipsum
\end{document}
```

If the expression is too long, I want it to be moved to start the next line. I have tried placing `\allowbreak` before the expression, but it does not change the result.

Comment: `~` *never* breaks, as far as I know, even with `\allowbreak`

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. Either you want it to break or you do not.... Do you want to force a linebreak before such a long construction if and only if it will not fit on the line. That may be possible.

Comment: the only approach i can see here is to end the first line short.  you can force the paragraph to re-flow by wrapping it in the environment `\begin{sloppypar) ... \end{sloppypar}`.  it won't look so good though.

Comment: This may be useful to create a macro that automatically breaks if word will not fit. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62333/push-long-words-in-a-new-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This steals directly from David's answer at [Push long words in a new line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62333/push-long-words-in-a-new-line)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\lword[1]{\leavevmode\nobreak\hskip0pt plus\linewidth\penalty50\hskip0pt plus-\linewidth\nobreak\textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
This text shows that non-breaking spaces are not working properly: \lword{``a:a~b:b~c:d~e:e~f:f~g:h''.} This is some lipsum

This shows that non-breaking spaces are not working properly: \lword{``a:a~b:b~c:d~e:e~f:f~g:h''.} This is some lipsum

This that non-breaking spaces are not working properly: \lword{``a:a~b:b~c:d~e:e~f:f~g:h''.} This is some lipsum

This spaces are not working properly: \lword{``a:a~b:b~c:d~e:e~f:f~g:h''.} This is some lipsum

This are not working properly: \lword{``a:a~b:b~c:d~e:e~f:f~g:h''.} This is some lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: protip: change `\textbf{#1}` to `#1` if you don't want it to be bolded in the output. ;-)