# long word exceeds page width

Tags: line-breaking

I have this word in my document:

```
--standard\_min\_confidence\_threshold\_for\_calling
```

It currently exceeds the page width. How can I make it start on the next line, so it doesn't exceed the page width? I should probably add that I'm new to tex.

Comment: after `\_` you could add `\linebreak[0]` to allow a break or `\-` if you want it to add a `-` if it breaks the word.

Comment: @david-carlisle So I have to insert a manual line break? And I have to modify that manual line break if the paragraph or sentence length changes? And I have to do this for all longs words? Oh dear...

Comment: @tommy.carstensen No but given no context in your question all I could give is the lowest level answer. The commands I suggested are all conditional line breaks so they only take effect if needed, eg you could use `\newcommand\myunder{\_\-}` then use `\myunder` instead of `\_`  or presumably this is some programming identifier and you could redefine the command used to display the program fragments to allow linebreaking or lots of other possibilities. But your question needs to give a few clues

Comment: @david-carlisle Sorry, I'm new to tex. I haven't reached a level yet, where I am able to ask good questions. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit: The `microtype` package probably also does what you want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultricies volutpat rhoncus.
Fusce suscipit molestie rhoncus. Fusce nec tristique purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus mi leo, pharetra vitae
nunc vitae, imperdiet tincidunt dui. Cras placerat pulvinar massa, non tincidunt eros auctor ac.
standard\_min\_confidence\_threshold\_for\_{} Ut molestie convallis dui, a malesuada nunc
aliquet et. standard\_min\_confidence\_threshold\_for\_{} Aliquam rhoncus diam a nunc volutpat
mollis. Fusce mattis congue diam, in porttitor sem. Nam ut eros et urna consectetur sollicitudin.
Cras mollis pulvinar dui, porta auctor diam ultricies a. Morbi ultricies gravida nisl vel ornare.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Nunc accumsan scelerisque magna, vel venenatis metus aliquam ornare. Vivamus sed mollis ipsum.
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: microtype]

Maybe also `sloppypar` is what you want to put around your paragraphs with the long words. It will look ugly and manual breaking the long words is certainly better, though at least you cannot have too long lines anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultricies volutpat rhoncus.
Fusce suscipit molestie rhoncus. Fusce nec tristique purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus mi leo, pharetra vitae
nunc vitae, imperdiet tincidunt dui. Cras placerat pulvinar massa, non tincidunt eros auctor ac.
standard\_min\_confidence\_threshold\_for\_{} Ut molestie convallis dui, a malesuada nunc
aliquet et. standard\_min\_confidence\_threshold\_for\_{} Aliquam rhoncus diam a nunc volutpat
mollis. Fusce mattis congue diam, in porttitor sem. Nam ut eros et urna consectetur sollicitudin.
Cras mollis pulvinar dui, porta auctor diam ultricies a. Morbi ultricies gravida nisl vel ornare.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Nunc accumsan scelerisque magna, vel venenatis metus aliquam ornare. Vivamus sed mollis ipsum.
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

Then you get

[image: sloppypar]

instead of this without `sloppypar`

[image: nosloppypar]

Comment: OK, now you added microtype. I will delete my answer. :-)

Comment: It's ok. We probably edited it at the same time ;)

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer to my own question here:
[How can I make my text never go over the right margin by always hyphenating or breaking on word-boundaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9107)

The trick is to add `\sloppy` right after `\begin{document}`. That did the trick for me.