# Text is spilling over the margin with standard margin settings

Tags: line-breaking

I have default margin settings, but certain text is spilling over the margin boundary. It happens when the final word on the line includes a hyphen. For example, if *eye-movement* happens to be at the end of the line, this can break the margin boundary.

It doesn't happen very often, but frequently enough to be a eyesore.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706)

Comment: The problem is  a word with a hyphen can be broken only at that hyphen (may be there are exceptions). Just imagine reading `eye-mo-vement`! Either you try to force breaking precisely at that point, or you rephrase your sentence so that the problem disappears.

Comment: Could you provide us with an MWE please, so that we can have your text. That way, we won't have to construct some text with a line ending in 'eye-movement' ourselves. As you can imagine, that will save a lot of tedious messing about and make your question much more attractive to us to answer

Comment: Wait till the very end of your project, then revise the text slightly or insert manual breaks if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Welcome! Make sure that you are are enabling hyphenation patterns for the correct language (in case TeX can find a break elsewhere) e.g. if you write in English, make sure you load patterns for the correct variant. Ensure that your text block has adequate width in terms of number of characters (i.e. not too narrow relative to the font size etc.). Try loading `microtype`. Problems like this are the exception rather than the rule so if you have several, something is either wrong or you have extreme typesetting requirements.

Comment: Check out this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/how-can-i-make-my-text-never-go-over-the-right-margin-by-always-hyphenating-or-b

Comment: For my case, I decided to go with @AndrewCashner's suggestion and revise the text at the end of the project. Thanks to all for the more detail candidates though.

Comment: If you use LuaLaTeX, see also [Enable extra hyphenation points for compound words that already contain a hyphen character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298793/5001)

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\sloppy % hyphenation for whole document
% use sloppypar environment for particular block of text
% no package is required

\begin{document}
text abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz eye-movement
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. The word sticks out into the margin.

Comment: The problem is TeX can't break the word combination. Why would making it unbreakable by a second means help?

Comment: The use of `\sloppy` for the entire document is ***not*** a good solution. I don't see that using `T1` or `lmodern` is likely to make any difference. Could you explain how these are supposed to help in what appears to be an English language document? (`T1` is recommended and `lmodern` is fine, although not my preference for LM support, so those are not bad suggestions - I just can't see why they'd help.)

Comment: `lmodern` is the font I use with `T1` encoding, it has nothing to do with hyphenation. Well, you could use `sloppypar` environment for hyphenation in certain parts of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution from this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193307/how-to-get-latex-to-hyphenate-a-word-that-contains-a-dash

If you add this line to your preamble:

`\def\hyph{-\penalty0\hskip0pt\relax}`

you can replace eye-movement with `eye\hyph{}movement` which will allow LaTeX to hyphenate the word even if it already contains a hyphen.