# Enable extra hyphenation points for compound words that already contain a hyphen character?

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation

Friends :), I would like to have compound words that contain hyphen characters, such as "Baden-Württemberg", to be permitted to be hyphenated at all points in the component words as well (here: "Ba-den" and "Würt-tem-berg").

I know of the discussions that this might look ugly, and I know that I could write something like `Ba\-den-Würt\-tem\-berg`. But I am providing a package for customer use, and it is hard to make everyone insert escape characters or manual hyphenation instructions on thousands (!) of pages of manuscript. Separation of form and content is, after all, one of the strong features of LaTeX.

So, is there an easy switch to disable the hyphenation prevention for words containing a hyphen? I have only access to the preamble of the document, so I cannot insert anything in the text.

I am using LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`, so hacking the `\hyphenchar` like in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63232/why-can-words-with-hyphen-char-not-be-hyphenated) doesn't work. 
Neither is it an option for me to insert `\hyphenation{Ba-den=Würt-tem-berg}` into the preamble for each word as was suggested in [this post.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen) I have to provide a package for *general* use.

I don't know if this question might be a duplicate.

Here is a MWE to play around with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[HyphenChar="2010] 
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[HyphenChar="2010] %does not work
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
Test electromagnetic-endioscopy
electromagnetic-endioscopy
electromagnetic-endioscopy
electromagnetic-endioscopy
Test electromagnetic-endioscopy
electromagnetic-endioscopy
electromagnetic-endioscopy
electromagnetic-endioscopy
electromagnetic-endioscopy
electromagnetic-endioscopy

\end{document}
```

Note that the `HyphenChar="2010` works only for Latin Modern and it prevents hyphenation *at* the hyphen. That makes it come close to the desired result but hyphenation at the hyphen if possible would be desirable.

Comment: If I load the main font as `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[HyphenChar="2010]`, with XeLaTeX the hyphenation turns out to be `Ba-den-Würt-tem-berg` (but no line break is taken at the explicit hyphen). This seems to have no effect with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: What can/should be assumed about the contents of the preamble of your document? E.g., is is OK to assume that `babel` is going to be loaded? If so, with which language option(s)?

Comment: @egreg thanks! I included it in the MWE in the question. It would be so much better if hyphenation at the hyphen would also happen if appropriate.

Comment: @Mico sure `babel` is included. English, french, ngerman would be the languages that will be mainly used.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting a bit to provide more background information on what you're looking to achieve. Hope that's OK with you. Seriously. :-)

Answer (score 10):

(Rewrote the answer to make the solution more like a standalone package.)

It's good news that you're using both LuaLaTeX and `babel`. :-)

The following proposed solution provides three files

- A .sty file, to be named `comphyph.sty` (short for "composite word full hyphenation"...), that loads the `babel` package, enables the `"=` shorthand for various languages, and sets up two TeX macros to turn the Lua code on and off
- A .lua file, to be named `comphyph.lua`, that contains the Lua code. Is loaded from `comphyph.sty`.
- A driver file that demonstrates how to use the code. It loads the `comphyph` package and runs through various exercises.

Important note: The code works by replacing all instances of `<letter>-<letter>` with `<letter>"=<letter>`, where `"=` is a babel shorthand macro. The code takes care *not* to perform these replacements inside `verbatim`, `Verbatim`, and `lstlisting` environments. The code also undoes the replacements if they're applied to the arguments of `\label`, `\ref` (as well as `\eqref`, `\vref`, `\autoref`, and `\cref`), `\url`, `\href`, `\cite`, and `\bibliography` macros. Use the Lua code below as a template to create further exceptions.

The file `comphyph.sty`:

```
%% comphyph.sty

\ProvidesPackage{comphyph}[2016/03/15]

%% Load the 'babel' package and enabling babel's '"' 
%% shorthand for languages other than "ngerman". 
%% Augment as needed.

\RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}

\addto\extrasbritish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}%
                     \useshorthands*{"}}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}%
                     \useshorthands*{"}}
\addto\extrasfrench{\languageshorthands{ngerman}%
                    \useshorthands*{"}}


%% Load the file that contains the Lua functions

\directlua{ dofile ( "comphyph.lua" ) }


%% Tex-side macros to enable/disable operation of 
%% "comphyph_ok" Lua function

\newcommand\comphyphOn{%
     \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback (
     "process_input_buffer",  comphyph_ok, "comphyph_ok" )}}

\newcommand\comphyphOff{%
     \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
     "process_input_buffer" , "comphyph_ok" )}}

\AtBeginDocument{\comphyphOn} % set to "on" by default
```

The file `comphyph.lua`:

```
-- comphyph.lua, 2016/03/16


-- Start by setting up a Boolean variable and
-- setting its default value to "false"

in_verbatim_or_listings = false

-- Do string substitution *except* if we're in a 
-- verbatim, Verbatim, or lstlistings environment

function comphyph_ok ( buff )
   if string.find ( buff , "\\begin{[vV]erbatim}" ) or
      string.find ( buff , "\\begin{lstlisting}" ) then
         in_verbatim_or_listings = true
         return buff
   elseif string.find ( buff , "\\end{[vV]erbatim}" ) or
      string.find ( buff , "\\end{lstlisting}" )then
         in_verbatim_or_listings = false
         return buff
   elseif in_verbatim_or_listings == false then
         buff = string.gsub (buff, '(%a)%-(%a)', '%1"=%2') 
         buff = undo_quote_equal ( buff )
         return buff
   end
end

-- Auxilliary function to undo string substitutions 
-- for text strings in arguments of macros such as
-- \label, \ref, \cite, \url, and \href

function undo_quote_equal ( s )
   s = string.gsub ( s , "(\\label%*?)(%b{})", 
           function ( macro, arg ) 
              arg = string.gsub ( arg , '"=', '-' )
              return macro..arg
           end)
   s = string.gsub ( s , "(\\%a*ref%*?)(%b{})", 
           function ( macro, arg ) 
              arg = string.gsub ( arg , '"=', '-' )
              return macro..arg
           end)
   s = string.gsub ( s , "(\\.-cite.-)(%b{})", 
           function ( macro, arg ) 
              arg = string.gsub ( arg , '"=', '-' )
              return macro..arg
           end)
   s = string.gsub ( s , "(%w%}?%}?%)?%])(%b{})", 
           function ( macro, arg ) 
              arg = string.gsub ( arg , '"=', '-' )
              return macro..arg
           end)
   s = string.gsub ( s , "(\\.-bib.-)(%b{})", 
           function ( macro, arg ) 
              arg = string.gsub ( arg , '"=', '-' )
              return macro..arg
           end)
   s = string.gsub ( s , "(\\url%*?)(%b{})", 
           function ( macro, arg ) 
              arg = string.gsub ( arg , '"=', '-' )
              return macro..arg
           end)
   s = string.gsub ( s , "(\\href%*?)(%b{})(%b{})", 
           function ( macro, arga, argb ) 
              arga = string.gsub ( arga , '"=', '-' )
              argb = string.gsub ( argb , '"=', '-' )
              return macro..arga..argb
           end)
   return s
end
```

A "driver" file that illustrates the use of the TeX and Lua code:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
%% Demo file for comphyph package

\documentclass{article}

% Create a dummy bib entry
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{my-bib.bib}
@misc{ x-y-z , author = "Author", title = "Title", year = 3001}
\end{filecontents}


%% Use either BibTeX/natbib or biber/biblatex 
%\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my-bib.bib}

\usepackage{url,amsmath}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage[british,english,french,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{comphyph} %% load the 'comphyph' package

\setlength\parindent{0pt}  % just for this demo file

\begin{document}
%% Verify that hyphenation of hyphenated words is on

\selectlanguage{english}
\parbox{1mm}{extra-terrestrial}

\smallskip
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\parbox{1mm}{Baden-Württemberg}

\smallskip
\selectlanguage{french}
\parbox{1mm}{laissez-passer}

\bigskip
\selectlanguage{english}

%% Set up a few cross-references

Dummy equation:
\begin{equation} \label{eq-pyth}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

Various cross-references: \ref{eq-pyth}, \eqref{eq-pyth}, \vref{eq-pyth}, \autoref{eq-pyth}, \cref{eq-pyth}.


%% Finally, create a citation call-out and generate the bibliography

\bigskip
A citation call-out: \cite{x-y-z}

%\bibliography{my-bib}  % if using BibTeX/natbib
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Screenshot of output produced by the preceding code:

[image]

Comment: By the way, I kept the word "endioscopy" because that's the way you spelled it in your posting. I believe the spelling "endoscopy" may be more prevalent.

Comment: Woooow thanks a lot! I'm trying this out now. Haha funny, I was copy pasting the "endioscopy" from this post: tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen

Comment: First, it works and thats amazing (yet another reason to use LuaTeX). 
There's one further caveat I believe: If a dash is used in a cite key, e.g. `\cite{Fank-Sinatra2003}`, biblatex will be searching for something like `Frank"=Sinatra2003` as a key in the database. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: @LaTechneuse - Arrgh. Fixing this properly is going to take some more work: I realize now that the arguments of certain macros -- `\cite`, `\url`, and `\href`, to name but three -- should be exempted from being processed by `multihyph_ok`, while it's OK to process the arguments of other macros, such as `\emph` and `\textbf`. Give me some time to think about how to address this situation.

Comment: ...and `lstlistings` too, if needed... I see it very difficult to find all the cases. Nevertheless, it's a good idea... and shows a very powerful option of LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Rmano - Thanks for this pointer. I'll post an addendum shortly, in which code is added to make sure that material inside an `lstlstings` environment isn't touched either.

Comment: @LaTechneuse - I've posted an addendum that addresses your follow-up query. Hopefully, the code in the new function `undo_quoteequal` is sufficiently self-explanatory to let you extend it to handle further macro-cum-argument cases.

Comment: I collect that you need to add the shorthand for each new language manually, so you still have to tamper with the preamble anyway. (I'm speaking here as a spanish user who may benefit from the projected package, as spanish doesn't pop up in the OP).

Comment: @erreka - I've re-written the answer to make it more straightforward to modify all or parts of the code, e.g., to add additional languages.

Comment: @LaTechneuse - I've rewritten and generalized the Lua code so that it should be robust to various occurrences of hyphenated words for which no substitution of `-` for `"=` should be undertaken. Let me know if you run into additional cases that require exceptions.

Comment: I wonder if a similar effect could be obtained simply by making `-` active, as in the old days...

Comment: @erreka - Making a selected character "active" is just a preparatory step. The hard part comes next: What is the character supposed to do?

Answer (score 4):

Use the german shortcuts of `babel`: `Baden"=Würtemberg` allows hyphenation at all possible breakpoints.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}% english is main language
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{sloppypar}
    Test electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    Testtttt Test electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    electromagnetic"=endioscopy
    \end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image]