# LuaLaTex Hyphenation not working with Times New Roman loaded

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, german, times

i have the problem that the Hyphenation ist nor working correctly when i have loaded the Font `Times New Roman`.

I'm using LuaLaTex and here you can see my MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
12pt,
DIV=calc,
oneside,
parskip=half                
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
Ligatures: fi fl ffl
whitespace Keynesian dwarfish calflike wolffish rufflike rooftop  \\ \\
Für die Autorisierung und Zugriffsverwaltung innerhalb und gegenüber dem X.500-Verzeichnisdienst wurden X.509-Zertifikate definiert, deren Zertifikatssyntax als \textit{Abstract Syntax Notation One} (ASN.1) bezeichnet wird.  Detailliertere Informationen zu ASN.1 sind zu entnehmen.
\end{document}
```

I tried also adding `\hyphenation{X.500=Ver-zeich-nis-dienst}` before `\begin{document}` but has no effect.

When i run the example without the command `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` or use instead `Times New Roman` the Font `Trebuchet MS`, it is working fine.

So could this be a problem with the `Times New Roman` Font? Or where is the problem?

Comment: yes the word that did not hyphen correctly is `X.500-Verzeichnisdienst`. I tried to put inside `\hypenation`command but did not work.

Comment: By the way (and off-topic): do not use `\\ \\ ` to create 'blank' space in your document.  (I realize that you may be doing so just for this example.)

Comment: See also: [Enable extra hyphenation points for compound words that already contain a hyphen character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298793/5001)

Comment: `\hyphenation{Ver-zeich-nis-dienst}` did not work. and yes the `\\`is only in this example - i don't use this either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX normally doesn't hyphenate a "word" which has a hyphen in other places. Use the babelshorthand "= to allow hyphenation in the rest of the word. Regarding the font: Different fonts means different line breaking.

```
\documentclass[%
a4paper,
12pt,
DIV=calc,
oneside,
parskip=half
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[babelshorthands]{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
Ligatures: fi fl ffl
whitespace Keynesian dwarfish calflike wolffish rufflike rooftop  \\ \\
Für die Autorisierung und Zugriffsverwaltung innerhalb und gegenüber dem X.500"=Verzeichnisdienst wurden X.509-Zertifikate definiert, deren Zertifikatssyntax als \textit{Abstract Syntax Notation One} (ASN.1) bezeichnet wird.  Detailliertere Informationen zu ASN.1 sind zu entnehmen.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not a problem with Times or any other font.

LuaTeX introduces new hyphenation features, but it doesn't change the fact that a character with zero `\lccode` ends the search for a word to hyphenate.

Thus `\hyphenation{X.500=Ver-zeich-nis-dienst}` does nothing at all, because `.500` all have zero `\lccode`.

```
\documentclass[%
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  DIV=calc,
  oneside,
  parskip=half                
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\lccode`.=`. \lccode`5=5 \lccode`0=`0
\hyphenation{X.500=Ver-zeich-nis-dienst}

Ligatures: fi fl ffl

whitespace Keynesian dwarfish calflike wolffish rufflike rooftop

Für die Autorisierung und Zugriffsverwaltung innerhalb und gegenüber 
dem X.500-Verzeichnisdienst wurden X.509-Zertifikate definiert, deren 
Zertifikatssyntax als \textit{Abstract Syntax Notation One} (ASN.1) 
bezeichnet wird.  Detailliertere Informationen zu ASN.1 sind zu entnehmen.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but another problem: how can i hyphen this word: `\textit{PolicyInformation}-Objekten` in the sentence `Die Erweiterung besteht aus einer Sequenz von einer oder mehreren \textit{PolicyInformation}-Objekten.` It did not break the word because the first part is inside the `\textit` command.

Comment: @Opa114 For this you need the `"=` method. But how many times do you have such a beast? Just add `\-` where you need.

Comment: ok. not often yes, so maybe the best solution will be to use `\-`

Comment: Could you please link to documentation of these "new hyphenation features" LuaLaTeX introduces?

Comment: @lblb The LuaTeX manual, section 4.3