# `microtype`: Set Minimum Width of a Space

Tags: xetex, luatex, microtype

### Problem Description

I am a newbie. I use `microtype` package. I would like to set the minimum width of a space to a width of a regular space. However, with default settings, it is shrinked too much and I think it makes the text less readable.

### Minimal Working Example

```
%%%%%  Preamble  %%%%%
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
% \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[
    paperheight=7cm,
    paperwidth=21cm,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    right=1in,
    left=1in,
    portrait]{geometry}

\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Font family
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

% Paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\cvlang}

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\paragraphStyle}[1]{%
    \par
    \begingroup
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\parskip}{0.16in}%
        \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}%
        \fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont
        \noindent\color{black!100}%
        \bfseries\ignorespaces #1\par
    \endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \paragraphStyle{
        Pripomenieme si Pánovo zmŕtvychvstanie, budeme počúvať
    }
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: output]

Comment: Do you want to change this for your paragraph or generally for the font?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I’d like to set it globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the WordSpace option to adjust the space. The value is a scale factor (3 is too much and only used for the demo here). It is also possible to adjust the stretch and shrink value individually, see the documentation of fontspec.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Font family
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[WordSpace={3}]
\begin{document}

        Pripomenieme si Pánovo zmŕtvychvstanie, budeme počúvať

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
% \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[
    paperheight=7cm,
    paperwidth=21cm,
    top=1in,
    bottom=1in,
    right=1in,
    left=1in,
    portrait]{geometry}

\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Font family
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, partial=upright, nabla=upright]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

% Paragraph and line settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}           % Set paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{0.08in}          % Paragraph spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}  % Line \expandafter\selectlanguage\expandafter{\cvlang}

% Custom commands
\newcommand{\paragraphStyle}[1]{%
    \par
    \begingroup
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\parskip}{0.16in}%
        \setlength\spaceskip{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt }% word space
        \setlength\xspaceskip{14pt plus 4pt minus 2pt }% end of sentence space
        \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}%
        \fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\selectfont
        \noindent\color{black!100}%
        \bfseries\ignorespaces #1\par
    \endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \paragraphStyle{
        Pripomenieme si Pánovo zmŕtvychvstanie, budeme počúvať
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain that `(x)spaceskip`? I think the space between words are now too wide. Is there a way to dynamically check/get the width of a space in particular font and set that width as minimal space width?

Comment: This is better: `\setlength\spaceskip{7pt plus 2pt minus 2pt }\n\setlength\xspaceskip{14pt plus 4pt minus 2pt }`, however, I have no idea what I am doing. ;)

Comment: And this solution moves the test in that particular line out into right margin (see [here](https://imgur.com/a/iUKoJRQ)).

Comment: The [`\sloppy`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9110/70043) fixed the overflow.